# Converting NSArray to Array in Swift produces nil to the Array Values

Tags: arrays, json, swift, dictionary, nsarray

I came into something I would assume is an easy enough problem but somehow I can't think of any way to solve it. It's simply converting an NSArray to an Array, and I think I've done a good job here with this code:

```
func getTrainingSubCategories(completion: @escaping(Result<[TrainingSubCategory], GetError>) -> Void){
    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: resourceURL){data, _, _ in
        guard let jsonData = data else {
            completion(.failure(.trainingCategoriesNoDataAvailable))
            return
        }
        do{
            let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData) as! [String: Any]
            for (key, value) in parsedData {
                if key == "categories" {
                    if let categoriesDictionary: [[String: Any]] = value as? [[String: Any]]{
                        for categoryDictionary in categoriesDictionary{
                            for (key, value) in categoryDictionary{
                                if key == "sub_categories" {
                                    print("1st Type => \(type(of: value)) Value => \(value)")
                                    print("2nd Type => \(type(of: value as? Array<TrainingSubCategory>)) Value => \(value as? Array<TrainingSubCategory>)")
//                                        guard let subCategoryValue = value as? Array<TrainingSubCategory> else{
//                                            fatalError("Error in casting value to array of trainingsubcategory")
//                                        }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch {
            completion(.failure(.trainingSubCategoriesCannotProcessData))
        }

    }
    dataTask.resume()
}
```

but the console would log otherwise:

```
1st Value => (
        {
        "category_id" = 1;
        "company_id" = 50;
        "created_at" = "2019-11-07 00:58:37";
        "deleted_at" = "<null>";
        id = 1;
        name = Advertisement;
        "updated_at" = "2019-11-07 00:58:37";
    },
        {
        "category_id" = 1;
        "company_id" = 50;
        "created_at" = "<null>";
        "deleted_at" = "<null>";
        id = 3;
        name = Sales;
        "updated_at" = "2019-11-10 23:28:30";
    }
)
2nd Value => nil
1st Value => (
        {
        "category_id" = 2;
        "company_id" = 50;
        "created_at" = "2019-11-07 19:58:07";
        "deleted_at" = "<null>";
        id = 6;
        name = Inventory;
        "updated_at" = "2019-11-07 19:58:07";
    }
)
2nd Value => nil
1st Value => (
        {
        "category_id" = 3;
        "company_id" = 50;
        "created_at" = "2019-11-10 21:24:22";
        "deleted_at" = "<null>";
        id = 9;
        name = "Human Resource";
        "updated_at" = "2019-11-10 21:24:22";
    }
)
2nd Value => nil
```

Am I missing something here? I'm quite new to Swift so I don't actually have much of a guess myself.

Comment: does your TrainingSubCategory clas/struct conforms to Codable protocol ?

Comment: You can't cast your values to an array of a specific type, you need to map the dictionaries manually to your custom type TrainingSubCategory. And as implied in the previous comment, maybe the easiest way forward is to us `Codable` for decoding your json

Comment: It's not an array of `TrainingSubCatgory`, it's an Array of Dictionaries. It's not parsed as TrainingSubCatgory, it's dictionries.

Comment: @KeshuRai, yes does. :)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, I already made it codable. I did what you said, manually mapping it to TrainingSubCategory. It worked perfectly, thank you! I'll show the code

Comment: @Larme I got that. I just thought I could make it conform to TrainingSubCategory array. Anyway, I'll show what I did as suggested by Larme

Comment: This would lead, however, to a different problem (__NSCFNumber to Int, and __NSCFString to String), but I think is something less of a problem now. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made the return type simply an array of NSDictionary.

```html
func getTrainingSubCategories(completion: @escaping(Result<[NSDictionary], GetError>) -> Void){
    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: resourceURL){data, _, _ in
        guard let jsonData = data else {
            completion(.failure(.trainingCategoriesNoDataAvailable))
            return
        }
        var trainingSubCategories = [NSDictionary]()
        do{
            let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData) as! [String: Any]
            for (key, value) in parsedData {
                if key == "categories" {
                    if let categoriesDictionary: [[String: Any]] = value as? [[String: Any]]{
                        for categoryDictionary in categoriesDictionary{
                            for (key, value) in categoryDictionary{
                                if key == "sub_categories" {
                                    if let subCategoriesArray: [Any] = value as? [Any] {
                                        for subCategory in subCategoriesArray{
                                            trainingSubCategories.append(subCategory as! NSDictionary)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                completion(.success(trainingSubCategories))
            }
        }catch {
            completion(.failure(.trainingSubCategoriesCannotProcessData))
        }
        
    }
    dataTask.resume()
}
```

and my function call with the return looks like this:

```html
private func downloadSubCategories(withCompanyID: Int) {
    let trainingCategoriesRequest = GetRequests(endpoint: "getTrainingCategories", id: String(withCompanyID))
    trainingCategoriesRequest.getTrainingSubCategories{result in
        switch result{
        case .success(let trainingSubCategories):
            for counter in 0 ..< trainingSubCategories.count {
                for (key, value) in trainingSubCategories[counter]{
                    print("\(key) => \(value)")
                }
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to map them without casting NSDictionary to TrainingSubCategory. Which, I'm sorry for ya'll looking into the post, is not an answer to the initial question but a workaround. :)